# How to get python unit test results in SonarQube?

Tags: python, unit-testing, configuration, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.  I've run nosetests to run python unit tests and create an xunit xml file called nosetests.xml.  I'm running Sonar Runner via the Sonar Jenkins plugin.  I've set the following Sonar properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=yauis
sonar.projectName=YAUIS
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=py
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=nosetests.xml
sonar.python.pylint=/usr/bin/pylint
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=coverage.xml
sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura
```

I'm seeing the following in the SonarQube Runner log:

```
...
15:31:20.355 INFO  - Sensor PythonXunitSensor...
15:31:20.363 INFO  - Processing report '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/nosetests.xml'
15:31:20.363 INFO  - Parsing report '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/nosetests.xml'
15:31:20.480 INFO  - Sensor PythonXunitSensor done: 125 ms
...
```

Here is a snippet from nosetests.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="nosetests" tests="30" errors="30" failures="0" skip="0">
    <testcase classname="nose.failure.Failure" name="runTest" time="0.000">
        <error type="exceptions.ImportError" message="cannot import name get_data_parameter&#xA;-------------------- &gt;&gt; begin captured logging &lt;&lt; --------------------&#xA;py.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:686: DeprecationWarning: The `blank` keyword argument is deprecated. Use the `required` keyword argument instead.&#xA;  super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)&#xA;&#xA;py.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:465: DeprecationWarning: The `blank` keyword argument is deprecated. Use the `required` keyword argument instead.&#xA;  super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)&#xA;&#xA;py.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqltypes.py:63: UserWarning: The blist library is not available, so a normal set will be used in place of blist.sortedset for set collection values. You can find the blist library here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/&#xA;  &quot;The blist library is not available, so a normal set will &quot;&#xA;&#xA;--------------------- &gt;&gt; end captured logging &lt;&lt; ---------------------"><![CDATA[File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 327, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/src/adminapi/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    from views import AdminApiViewHandler
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/src/adminapi/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from common.ViewUtils import json_response, get_data_parameter
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/src/common/ViewUtils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from common.utils import get_application_uri
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/src/common/utils.py", line 550, in <module>
    from common.managers.formfactormanager import FormfactorModifier
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/src/common/managers/formfactormanager.py", line 3, in <module>
    from common.ViewUtils import get_data_parameter
'cannot import name get_data_parameter\n-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------\npy.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:686: DeprecationWarning: The `blank` keyword argument is deprecated. Use the `required` keyword argument instead.\n  super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)\n\npy.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:465: DeprecationWarning: The `blank` keyword argument is deprecated. Use the `required` keyword argument instead.\n  super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)\n\npy.warnings: WARNING: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yauis/workspace/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqltypes.py:63: UserWarning: The blist library is not available, so a normal set will be used in place of blist.sortedset for set collection values. You can find the blist library here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/\n  "The blist library is not available, so a normal set will "\n\n--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------']]></error>
    </testcase>
...
```

The unit test results are not showing in SonarQube.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issues with SonarQube 4.2+ that has been fixed but not released yet: [SONARPY-37](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPY-37)

You should stay tuned and wait for version 1.4 of the Python plugin.

Comment: Has this fix been put into trunk yet?
We're running SonarQube version 4.5.1

Comment: Well, if you take a look at the JIRA ticket that I mentioned in the answer, you will see the answer to your question...